# All-or-nothing placing of macro-generated text

Tags: macros, formatting, positioning

Given a macro

```
% bold task titles
\newcommand{\mypar}[1]{{\bf #1:}}

%task decription template
\newcommand{\task}[3]{
    \mypar{#1} #2 \\
    \emph{Solution:} #3\\
}
```

I should like for the text generated by a `task` macro to be an atomic unit. I.e. it either fits entirely into the space left on a page or all of it (and everything following it) is pushed to the next page.

What can I do to this macro to enforce this?

Comment: Enclose it in `\begin{samepage}...\end{samepage}`.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't do anything, I'm afraid.